# Accomplishing `A.merge(B).merge(C).merge(D) ....` using `pandas.concat()`

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dozen data frames like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(5) ,'col2': np.random.rand(5)})
A.index = [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555]
B = pd.DataFrame({'col3': np.random.rand(5) ,'col4': np.random.rand(5)})
B.index = [77777, 22222, 33333, 55555, 88888
```

]

I would like to do an outer join on the indices. I can obtain the desired result using `A.merge(B)` with the following:

```
A.merge(B, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

yielding

```
           col1      col2      col3      col4
11111  0.195266  0.765243       NaN       NaN
22222  0.524872  0.978260  0.769246  0.318719
33333  0.581588  0.391997  0.962788  0.864938
44444  0.490709  0.082014       NaN       NaN
55555  0.339119  0.807546  0.545300  0.378834
77777       NaN       NaN  0.345498  0.634918
88888       NaN       NaN  0.976489  0.871800
```

This is what I want. Unfortunately, `.merge()` is very slow for large dataframes, and elsewhere on this site, I have read that I should use `pd.concat()` instead. But in this case, `pd.concat([A, B])`
does not work, because it does not accept the `left_index` and `right_index` keywords. Instead it just stacks the two on top of one another:

```
           col1      col2      col3      col4
11111  0.195266  0.765243       NaN       NaN
22222  0.524872  0.978260       NaN       NaN
33333  0.581588  0.391997       NaN       NaN
44444  0.490709  0.082014       NaN       NaN
55555  0.339119  0.807546       NaN       NaN
77777       NaN       NaN  0.345498  0.634918
22222       NaN       NaN  0.769246  0.318719
33333       NaN       NaN  0.962788  0.864938
55555       NaN       NaN  0.545300  0.378834
88888       NaN       NaN  0.976489  0.871800
```

Is there a way to accomplish this join using `pd.concat()`? Or am I stuck with `merge`?

Comment: You have to `concat` along the columns axis. Check with `pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use axis=1 to change the axis to concatenate along, which is default 0:

```
C = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
print(C)
```

output will like this:

```
           col1      col2      col3      col4
11111  0.707499  0.644641       NaN       NaN
22222  0.971488  0.320773  0.528505  0.257957
33333  0.173358  0.244919  0.899253  0.305035
44444  0.544763  0.101368       NaN       NaN
55555  0.160257  0.456790  0.834480  0.889750
77777       NaN       NaN  0.339059  0.968170
88888       NaN       NaN  0.315871  0.984425
```

for more detail about how to merge, you can see the offical document:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html